# Change a tag of metadata from jpg with python

Tags: python, tags, metadata, jpeg

I would to know if is it posible to change the tag mark on the image with python:

[image]

I've tried using pyexif and directly PIL but i cant found the tag or the way to change it in python.

Thanks

Comment: See [this exiftool forum post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=6591.msg32875#msg32875) where I documented the exiftool tag names to write to fill the Windows properties display.  For example, to fill "Comentarios" ("Comments" in Eng), you would write to any one of `EXIF:UserComment`, `EXIF:XPComment`, or `XMP-exif:UserComment` using [PyExifTool ](https://pypi.org/project/PyExifTool/).

Comment: Note that `EXIF:XPComment` is pretty much a Windows only tag and is rarely used by software other than Windows. This is the case for all the `EXIF:XP*` tags listed on the forum post.  This is different than XMP, which is a completely different group.